# Adding condition on the value of property of parent node to set value of property of child node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have the following graph in my database:

[image]

There is a **confidential_requirement** at **Node 1** that I need to put a condition on at **Node 4**. I need to set the value of **rating** at **Node 4** based on the value from **Node 1**. I am not getting an idea about how to do this. Here is my create script:

```
CREATE 
(App4:App {name:          'Consumer Banking Portal No Review',  confidential_requirement: 'high', integrity_requirement: 'high', availability_requirement: 'high',           inherent_risk_rating: 'critical', crown_jewel_application: 'yes', internet_facing: 'yes', average_transaction: '100', max_number_of_daily_transaction: '200',         number_of_pii_record: '5000' }),

(feat1: FEATURE {name: "Update_Profile", desc: "update customer profile"}),

(gf_query: GENERIC_FEAT {name: "QUERY_INFO",  desc: "retrieve info"}),

(t_auth_read: THREAT {name: "Auth_Read_t", desc: "Compromise authorization in query info", impact: "Information Disclosure", rating: ""}),


(App4)-[:HAS]->(feat1),
(feat1)-[:HAS]->(gf_query),
(gf_query)-[:HAS]->(t_auth_read);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so clear how do you want to identify these specific nodes, but If you want to use their names and distance between them, One option is:

```
MATCH (a:App{name:'Consumer Banking Portal No Review'})-[*0..3]->(b:THREAT{name: 'Auth_Read_t'})
SET b.rating = a.confidential_requirement
RETURN a, b
```